# composite primary key realm/swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm new to swift and realm. I want to make a composite primary key and when I'm trying something like this :

```
class DbLocation : Object {
 dynamic var id = 0
 dynamic var tourId = 0

 dynamic var uuid : String  {
    return "\(id)\(tourId)"
 }

 override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "uuid"
 }
}
```

I'm getting this error : 
'Primary key property 'uuid' does not exist on object 'DbLocation'

Anyone can help me out with an example how to create a composite primary key ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For `1.0.1+` of Realm:

```
class DbLocation: Object{
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var tourId = 0
    dynamic var compoundKey = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "compoundKey"
    }

    func setup(id: Int, tourId: Int){
        self.id = id
        self.tourId = tourId
        self.compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
        return "\(id)\(tourId)"
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
let location = DbLocation()
location.setup(id: 0, tourId: 1) 
print(location.compoundKey) // "01"
```

Of course you can play around with using various `didSet` listeners on `id` and `tourId`, to make sure that compoundKey gets properly rewritten every time the values get changed.

For `pre-1.0.1` of Realm:

```
class DbLocation: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var tourId = 0

    func setCompoundID(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    func setCompoundTourId(tourId: Int) {
        self.tourId = tourId
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    dynamic lazy var compoundKey: String = self.compoundKeyValue()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "compoundKey"
    }

    func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
        return "\(id)\(tourId)"
    }
}
```

The custom setters make sure, that the compoundKey is always updated, the lazy key word makes sure that the first time you access it, it will be derived from what you've already set.

Find out more on this topic in [this thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1192) where this issue has been debated.

Comment: if we declare composite key variable like this: dynamic lazy var fullName: String = "\(self.id)-\(self.tourId)" then what is problem in that ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Swift lazy properties are explicitly forbidden, unless they are ignored. How do we solve this issue now @Michal?

Comment: I got Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Lazy managed property 'compoundKey' is not allowed on a Realm Swift object class. Either add the property to the ignored properties list or make it non-lazy.'

Comment: @BlackTiger The only way is to channel the writes to `id` and `tourId` only through `setCompoundID(id: Int)` and `setCompoundTourId(tourId: Int)` functions, so you know for sure that a latest `compoundKey` has been written, then you can save the realm. Also if you choose to implement things this way, then you can remove `lazy` keyword and `self.compoundKeyValue()`

Comment: Hi, I am getting "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Lazy managed property 'compoundKey' is not allowed on a Realm Swift object class. Either add the property to the ignored properties list or make it non-lazy." on lazy compound key.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be valid as it causes a runtime error

Answer (score 1):

Simple create a new property whose value is set to interested other properties which you expect to be compound primary keys.

```
class DbLocation: Object {
            dynamic var id = 0
            dynamic var tourId = 0
            dynamic var compoundKey: String? = ""

        override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
                return "compoundKey"
            }
        }
    let location = DbLocation()
    location.tourId = 1
    location.id = 5
    location.compoundKey = "\(id) \(tourId)"
```

Comment: sorry bud, but we already know workarounds ( as in your answer ), but the discussion about native support of compound keys has been going on for some time and the issue is tracked here : https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3453

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of Swift and Realm, I would do something like this.

```
dynamic private var compoundKey: String = ""

required convenience init?(map: Map) {
  self.init()
  if let firstValue = map.JSON["firstValue"] as? String,
    let secondValue = map.JSON["secondValue"] as? Int {
    compoundKey = firstValue + "|someStringToDistinguish|" + "\(secondValue)"
  }
}
```