# composite primary key with realm 1.0.1 on swift

Tags: swift, swift2, realm

Lastest Realm Swift 1.0.1 
I do follow this 
[composite primary key realm/swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265666/composite-primary-key-realm-swift)

[image]

It's shows error following

[image]

How to i can write with Swift?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to drop the `lazy` specifier from the variable declaration as how the error messages states such properties are not supported. You don't want to ignore the property as you want to use it as a primary key.

Beside that I would recommend to separate your integer components within your compound key. (e.g. `"\(id)|\(tourId)"`) Otherwise you can end up having different objects with the same conflicting primary key. e.g. You could have objects with `compoundKey="123"` for the combination `id=1 tourId=23`, but also for `id=12 tourId=3`.