# How to set Realm primaryKey on a class "sub-property"

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Say I have a class and its Realm representation that looks like this:

```
class Dog {
    var identifier: String
    var age: Int
    ...

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identifier"
    }
}
```

Now here is what my new Identifier class looks like:

```
class Identifier {
    var functionalId: String
    var version: String
    ...
}
```

I need to replace my Dog's identifier String property to be an Identifier like this:

```
class Dog {
    var identifier: Identifier
    var age: Int
    ...

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identifier" // I need to change this
    }
}
```

but I'm having a hard time replacing the content of the primaryKey() method:

How do I tell Realm to look for an object's sub property for the primaryKey() ?

I tried something like:

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "identifier.functionalId"
}
```

But it seems that I was too naive, it won't work

** **EDIT** ** Following comments, here is the output of the crash I'm getting:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Primary key property 'identifier.functionalId' does not exist on object Dog
```

Sorry for bad English though, I couldn't find the words fir this simple problem, especially the title!

Comment: "I'm having a hard time replacing the content" > are you getting any errors reported by Realm?

Comment: Thanks for asking, I edited the question to include the crash's log

Comment: What error do you get if you just set it to`"identifier"` rather than `"identifier.functionalId`?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Property 'identifier' cannot be made the primary key of 'Dog' because it is not a 'string' or 'int' property.'

Comment: I think that answers the question then! The primary key can only be a `String` or `Int`, and can only be a property on `Dog`. I'll add an answer below.

Comment: Have a look at [Composite primary key Realm Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265666/composite-primary-key-realm-swift), the same workaround should work for your case as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this in Realm, but it might be possible using a dynamic variable for your primary key and a function that pulls the value from the sub-object:

```
var _identifier: Identifier

dynamic lazy var identifier: String = self.identifierValue()

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "identifier"
}

func identifierValue() -> String {
    return _identifier.functionalId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I tell Realm to look for an object's sub property for the
>   primaryKey()

You can't.

**Looking at the errors you've mentioned:**

If you try setting the primary key to:

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "identifier"
}
```

Then you get an error from Realm saying: `Property 'identifier' cannot be made the primary key of 'Dog' because it is not a 'string' or 'int' property.`

If you try setting the primary key to:

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "identifier.functionalId"
}
```

Then you get an error from Realm saying: `Primary key property 'identifier.functionalId' does not exist on object Dog`

**This leads to the conclusion that the primary key must be of type `String` or `Int`, and it must be a property of `Dog`, not another class.**

Comment: This does not answer the question, it's just a compilation of the comments and was part of the research I did before asking.

Comment: Yes, but it is the answer, because you cannot do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've updated the answer explicitly replying to your question.